# Best method to create dynamic Html Controls In MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have requirement to create dynamic Html controls and display it in view using MVC in .Net and also i need to do some basic validation i.e - if it is textbox then it should not be empty and if it is checkbox and validate the checkbox is checked or not. same time after successfull validation i need to save it in DB.

Would you please tell me which approach is best to achieve this? it should not affect the preformance.I have some list of options in mind
1. Using HTMLhelperclass,string builder,Tag builder.
2. Jquery

I dont know which option is easy and best to achieved.

Comment: The tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc cover this and much more, definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLHelper` classes would be of great help.
If you need to implement basic validations like `Required` field or with some `RegEx` then you can rely on the validation attributes that MVC provides and use it with your `Model`
e.g

```
[Required]
Public string FirstName {get; set;}
```

You can also write your own custom attributes and use it on your `Model` classes

[This could be of great help](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

A rough sketch for dynamic UI

Write a `model` class that is bound to your DB (this will contain the details of your UI controls like `type,name,attributes` etc.). When your default `controller` action is hit for the first time, initialize your `model` and pass it on to the corresponding `View`, which is bound to your `Model`. 
Its pretty simple then, you can read the model values in the `View` and accordingly place your UI elements using `HTMLHelper` methods

Comment: but i am creating dynamic HTML page and no of HTMl controls is based upon the list from DB. your answer fullfill my Validation part.but how do i create HTMl control dymanicaly and save the data to DB

Comment: can i use JSON2HTML to achieve my requirement. JSON2HTML script creates the HTML tag dynamically.